# MVVM - In a list of objects, each containing a command, how can I get the appropriate command to fire?

Tags: mvvm, commandbinding

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but in my view model I have a list of objects (CGCAppSwitchboardItem) that each contain a DelegateCommand property. My intention here is that each item (CGCAppSwitchboardItem) in my list would represent a module inside my solution whereby a call to the command will load a module. Or, better said, I am using this list to build a list of buttons or menu items that will open the requested view when selected.

The problem that I have is that the last CGCAppSwitchboardItem's command is the one that gets fired regardless of the button pushed. I have tested this by adding them in different order, and whichever is added last, that's the command that gets fired. How can I get the appropriate command to fire?

**Edit: I've narrowed the problem down and don't know what to do about it. The problem is occurring in the generic function that I'm creating when assigning it to the RunMethod. If you look at the code below, I'm assigning the RunMethod when creating the CGCAppSwitchboardItem class. If you look at my generic function, I'm passing in the itm.ModuleName property. Apparently, the newly created delegate, the one I'm assigning to the RunMethod, is keeping a reference to itm.ModuleName instead of the string value to which I want. Since this is in a loop, the itm variable remains set to the last module in the list. Therefore, when the RunMethod() is called, it references itm.ModuleName instead of "MyModuleName". Any ideas?**

```
public class CGCAppSwitchboardItem : ISwitchboardItem
{                
    public Action RunMethod { get; set; } //RunMethod gets assigned by external ViewModel

    public ICommand ExecuteCommand { get; set; }

    public CGCAppSwitchboardItem()
    {
        ExecuteCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(
            o =>
            {                   
                if (RunMethod != null)
                {
                    RunMethod();
                }
            }, 
            o =>
            {
                return (RunMethod != null);
            });
    }               
} 


public class CGCApplicationShellViewModel : ICGCApplicationShellViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, ISwitchboardListContainer
{
```

//...REMOVED CODE FOR BREVITY 
        private void PopulateSwitchboardItems()
        {
            if (_moduleCatalog != null)
            {
                _switchBoardItems.Clear();

```
            foreach (var itm in _moduleCatalog.Modules)
            {
                _switchBoardItems
                    .Add(
                        new CGCAppSwitchboardItem()
                            {
                                Name = itm.ModuleName,
                                RunMethod = () => 
                                 {
```

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(itm.ModuleName);
                                            _moduleManager.LoadModule(itm.ModuleName);
                                            //_moduleManager.LoadModule("ATimesheetModule");
                                        }
                                }
                            );
                }
            }
        }

```
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:WTSSwitchBrdItm="clr-namespace:WTS.CGCApplicationInterface.Switchboard"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="150">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowModule">
        <Button Name="btnOpenView" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"
                Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}">                
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="15" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image x:Name="imgAvatar" Source="{Binding Path=Avatar}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" >
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat=" ({0})">
                        <Binding Path="Description"/>                  

                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SwitchboardItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShowModule}"></ListBox>
</Grid> </UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the CommandParameter to identify the record:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RecordId}" />
```